# How can I properly determine the value of a variable based on where the slider is

Tags: c++, math

So I am trying to make a UI system and I am currently working on a slider. The sliders are meant to help me change a variable's value quickly when my application is running. It consists of 2 rectangles. `tRect` is the horizontal on a slider and `tSliderRect` is the vertical rectangle that the user can move. I am setting the initial position of `tSliderRect` based on the value of the variable. The following code only runs in the first frame. My problem here is that it does not work if `min` has a negative value.

```
//min and max are for the variable's value
void SliderInit(const float variable, const float min, const float max) noexcept
{
    //these positions are also adjusted depending on where the window is
    //but that is done later and not important for this question.
    tSliderRect.x = (variable / max) * tRect.width;
    tSliderRect.width = 0.08f * tRect.width;
    tSliderRect.y = tRect.height - (0.25f * tRect.height);
    tSliderRect.height = 1.5f * tRect.height;
}
```

Same problem later when I try to calculate the variable's value depending on the position of `tSliderRect`. This is what I have. I don't know how I would adjust for `min`. What if min is negative?

```
void SetVariableValue(float& variable, float min, float max) const noexcept
{
    variable = (tSliderRect.x / tRect.width) * max;
}
```

Essentially, I want to map the values from `tSliderRect.x` to `tRect.width` into `min` to `max`. Thanks.

Here is a lousy drawing to help my explanation.

[image]

Comment: I think the more appropriate statement in the drawing would be "Function to map a given point in the above line to the line bellow"

Comment: Why not save yourself all this time in development when you could use an existing GUI framework?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am really just trying to learn c++ while also making something useful

Comment: `w = tSliderRect.x / tRect.width`. Are you saying `w` is between 0 and 1? If so then the formula you want is `min + (max - min) * w`.

Comment: @Matt y is always constant. Only x matters

Comment: I meant to define a new variable. I replaced `y` with `w` above.

Comment: @Matt Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clamping a value to a range (sort of)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271425/clamping-a-value-to-a-range-sort-of)